# Change parent's state using funciton in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to re render data using setState [child to parent] ? deleteItem function in FoodList should delete the selected data and re render it. Im not asking for delete code but on how will i re render the main component having a function inside child component which should deleteItem does the re rendering

I have a 3 components. Main, Food and FoodList.

Main Component - Holds the list of food in array via state and pass it as props to Food Component.

```js
class Main extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            foods: []
        };
    }
    
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            foods: [
                {
                    id: uui.v4(),
                    name: "Chocolate Cake",
                    category: "dessert"
                },
                {
                    id: uui.v4(),
                    name: "Milkshake",
                    category: "beverage"
                }
            ]
        });
    }
    
    render(){
        return(<Food lists={this.state.foods}/>);
    }
}
```

Food Component - maps the recieved lists props of food and pass it to FoodList Component to render as lis

```js
class Food extends Component{
    render(){
        let items;
        //check if object has value;
        if(this.props.lists)
        {
            items = this.props.lists.map(food => {
                //pass each food as props
                return <FoodList key={food.id} food_list={food} />;
            });
        }
        
        return(
            <div>
            <h3>Available Foods</h3>
            {items}
            </div>
        ); 
    }
}
```

FoodList Component - recieves the mapped props and render as li

```js
class FoodList extends Component {
    
    deleteItem(id)
    {
        console.log(id);
        //delete item using passed id and re rende food state in Main Component
    }
    
    render(){
        return <li>{this.props.food_list.name} - {this.props.food_list.category}
        <a href="#" onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, this.props.food_list.id)}>Delete</a>
        </li>
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note, you can set your state in your constructor and get rid of componentWillMount

Comment: sir i am following a tutorial on youtube which he preferred componentWillMount() ? which do you think sir is the best option?

Comment: If you already have the data (which you do) then I would assign it to state in the constructor. You are already assigning foods: [], and then again in componentWillMount. You can do it all in the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create a method on the parent component and pass it as a prop to the child component

example

```
class Main extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          foods: []
        };
    }

    deleteFood = (id) => {
      let foods = this.state.foods;
      let index = -1;
      for(let i = 0; i < foods.length; i++){
        if(foods[i].id == id){
          index = i;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(index == -1){
        return;
      }
      foods.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({foods: foods});
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            foods: [
            {
                id: uui.v4(),
                name: "Chocolate Cake",
                category: "dessert"
            },
            {
                id: uui.v4(),
                name: "Milkshake",
                category: "beverage"
            }
            ]
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(<Food deleteFood={this.deleteFood} lists={this.state.foods}/>);
    }
}
```

do the same for rendering FoodList in your Food component

```
<FoodList key={food.id} food_list={food} deleteFood={this.props.deleteFood} />
```

and finally use it in your foodlist component

```
deleteItem(id)
    {
        console.log(id);
        this.props.deleteFood(id);
        //delete item using passed id and re rende food state in Main Component
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to bind 'this' to deletFood

Comment: Hi @TMitchell I think you don't need to use bind when using an arrow function

Comment: correct, but the properties of the React class instance aren't bound automatically. They are when using React.createClass, but they aren't when extending React.Component - https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/#reactcomponent-3

Comment: @TMitchell yes that's right for properties like 
`hello(){}`
but, `hello = ()=>{}` will preserve 'this'..
that's what I use in my code :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your Main component

```
deleteItem(id) {
  this.setState({
    foods: this.state.data.filter(food => food.id !== id)
  })
}
```

Pass it through your Components

```
<Food lists={this.state.foods} deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}/>
```

-

```
items = this.props.lists.map((food, index) => {
  return <FoodList key={food.id} food_list={food} deleteItem={this.props.deleteItem}/>;
});
```

Invoke it onClick of your delete button

```
deleteItem(id) {
  this.props.deleteItem(id);
}

<a href="#" onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, id)}>Delete</a>
```

Comment: SIr I am truly new to React.. Should I always make a function to the Main and pass it as props?

Comment: That is one way of doing things. Another is to look into Flux for more advanced/larger scale applications (google flux and redux). In this instance, if you want to edit the state of a parent component, the modifying function will need to come from that same component